# How to print string before specific word in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to learn how to extract only the Kernel Version from this specific output:

```
3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64Repository rhel-7-server-optional-rpms is listed more than once in the configuration
```

This is the output that I am aiming for: `3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64`

Comment: It took me a while to understand the question title even its content is quite clear. Anyway [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393948/how-to-search-and-extract-string-from-command-output) could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways.
A "simple" is using sed with a regex to replace the part that you want to strip.
Ex:

```
echo "3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64Repository rhel-7-server-optional-rpms" | sed -E "s/Repository.*//"

3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64
```

To explain the `sed` command used :   `sed -E "s/Repository.*//"` :

E` is for extended regular expression.
And sed syntax substitution is :

> `s/regexp/replacement/`
>
> Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space. If successful,
> replace that portion matched with replacement

Here we replace the string found by nothing.

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```sh
var="3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64Repository rhel-7-server-optional-rpms"
echo "${var%%Repository*}"
```

See [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual.